# Analytics of one particular video?

Tags: analytics, vimeo

Has anyone using the Vimeo API created a way to "pull" the analytics from 1 single video (i.e. # of views, unique views, full (to the end) views, etc.)?...

I'm thinking this would be useful to embed in a password protected area on my site for some of my clients for their particular video...just the stats (up until the last day, doesn't have to be real time as-of-this-second) ...

I'm new to the Vimeo API, but definitely not new to coding + backend development work. I thought I'd try to not reinvent the wheel if this has already been done. :)

Thx, and cheers :)

Jeff

Comment: In the last 3 months did you find a solution to this issue?